# Open files as tabs in Gedit

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, gedit

There is one thing about gedit that really makes me nervous :@.

If I open some file from the terminal, for exampe

```
gedit ~/some_file.txt &
```

pop up an window with the file, then if I open another one

```
gedit ~/some_file2.txt &
```

it opens the file in the same window (just in a new tab), that is great.

The problem comes when I open some 3rd file from the file manager, it opens the file in new window instead of new tab, which makes me very angry.

How to solve this >?

Comment: Why I got -1 ? can you please explain what seems to be the problem with this question ?

Comment: This question belongs to the [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com) site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a well-known issue with gedit. It is because of the algorithm it uses to check whether to open the new file in the same instance (as a tab) or in a new one. Fortunately, a solution is available [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75671/why-does-gedit-keep-randomly-opening-new-instances-when-opening-files-from-nauti).

Answer (score -1):

BTW, the gedit I'm using ( 2.30.4) has an option under the "Documents" menu to open a tab in a new window.